# Sending a message through a url

Tags: php

I have an application that allows me to send as sms in a url using my android phone as follows:

```
http://196.96.53.25/sendsms? phone=0724206400&text=Yusuf_kiprop
```

however, when I remove the underscore from the text as follows:

```
http://196.96.53.25/sendsms?phone=0724206400&text=Yusuf kiprop
```

I get an error that webpage is unavailable. What could be the issue?

Comment: If your browser does not URL encode by default, then you will receive this error. PHP will automaticly decode URL parameters, so you can use %20 instead of a space. Also see function http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: send sms using curl

Answer (score 1):

If you are sending from php  then encode the message like

```
$message=urlencode('Yusuf kiprop');
http://196.96.53.25/sendsms?phone=0724206400&text=$message
```

If you are checking it in the browser directly its not being url encoded thats why.
Try this insted-:

```
http://196.96.53.25/sendsms?phone=0724206400&text=Yusuf%20kiprop
```